# ¿Como Concatenar datos a un jtextfield con MouseListener?

Tags: java, jtable, jtextfield

Espero ser claro, tengo un codigo que me saca los datos de una base a un JTable al hacer click en una columna la de email en este caso lo pasa a un JTextField creado con anterioridad, mi pregunta es ¿Como hacer que al dar click en otra celda de la misma columna lo ponga en el mismo JTextField separado por ";"
este es mi codigo, (solo del mouse listener)-

```
 private void tbldatosMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                      
  tbldatos.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent Mouse_evt) {
            JTable table = (JTable) Mouse_evt.getSource();
            Point point = Mouse_evt.getPoint();
            int row = table.rowAtPoint(point);
                if (Mouse_evt.getClickCount()==1){
                 destino.setText(tbldatos.getValueAt(tbldatos.getSelectedRow(), 7).toString());


                }


        }


    });
}
```

alguien sabe la respuesta?

gracias anticpadas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solo hay que modificar un poco, te quedaría algo como esto:

```
 private void tbldatosMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                      
     tbldatos.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
         public void mousePressed(MouseEvent Mouse_evt) {
             JTable table = (JTable) Mouse_evt.getSource();
             Point point = Mouse_evt.getPoint();
             int row = table.rowAtPoint(point);
             if (Mouse_evt.getClickCount()==1){
                 String datoSeleccionado = tbldatos.getValueAt(tbldatos.getSelectedRow(), 7).toString();
                 if (destino.getText().isEmpty()){
                     destino.setText(datoSeleccionado);
                 } else {
                     String datoAnterior = destino.getText();
                     destino.setText(datoAnterior + "; " + datoSeleccionado);
                 }
             }
         }
     });
}
```

Espero que te sirva

Comment: Muchas gracias sirvio casi perfecto, solo que me añade 2 veces el segundo 3 veces el tercero... asi sucesivamente

Comment: Lo que pasa es que cada que haces click va agregando un nuevo MouseListener... lo que tienes que hacer es sacar todo el código que está dentro de tbldatosMouseClicked y lo pones fuera.

Comment: Increible amigo ya funciono!!!!!!!! muchas gracias por tu ayuda eres el mejor!